# Calculating when float would reach 0 ahead of time

Tags: loops, floating-point, future

I have a loop, that runs at `1000 / 60` ~ `16.67`ms.

I have a percentage float (`0.0 - 1.0`), and each iteration I subtract `.05` from.

How do I calculate which iteration in future will set my percentage float to `0`?

I have a feeling that this is simple math, but I just cannot think of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Float/0.05 = number of iterations it will take to reach 0 (assuming float is neatly divisible by 0.05). If it isn't, it'll be ceiling(YourFloat/0.05).